# Nativescript Firebase Login and Registration

Tags: angular, firebase, angular2-nativescript

I have just started using Native script & Angular for developing apps. I opted for google firebase as by database source. I have managed to migrate my SQL data to firebase real-time database. I can retrieve the data from the json table fine.
Now my question in terms of Login and Registration, can I query the username and passwords for logging in or do I have to use Firebase Authentication option with the email and password

Comment: Yes you can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467492/how-to-provide-user-login-with-a-username-and-not-an-email

Comment: Thank you got it

Answer (score 0):

I am looping values from my firebase database using objectKey technique.

```
uid:fcnb8wD7ZdgqfBYrUVUfW5Z1Azm2
 {
   "zcash_": 1.32569,
   "machine": true,
   "litecoin": 5.3655,
   "decred": 6.25663,
  "btc": 0.2364144
 }
```

I m retrieving the BTC value. It returns the value but appends undefined twice before it shows the value I need. how can I eliminate the undefined values

```
 firebase.getValue(`/machinelist/${userID}`)
      .then(
        result =>   Object.keys(result).forEach(key => {
var balance= result[key]['btc'];
console.log(balance);
        }
      )
      .catch(error => console.log("Error: " + error));
```

This is how i am iterating my json object