# how to sign a user up without e mail password

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello I am doing a weather app, and I don't need users to sign up with e mail and password. I want to sign them up using just their names and store their names in firebase if possible and address them their name inside the app. How to do this?

Comment: Why would you need Firebase for that at all? I don't know your use case, but from what you've said here, I think storing the name in `SharedPreferences` (or something like that) would suffice.

Comment: You need to edit the database rules to allow for non-users to make changes.

Comment: This is a bad idea, if you have 2 people with the same "name", it breaks your logic.

Comment: The most common way used to be to just add a random domain to the name, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467492/how-to-provide-user-login-with-a-username-and-not-an-email. But the better approach these days would be to implement this as custom authentication as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120939/username-authentication-instead-of-email (which has the same link as Lucien shared).

Answer (score 1):

There is an official example [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/username-password-auth)