# Add a default domain to the email being registered

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I created an app with react and firebase authentication
I wish that during registration / login, I only need to enter the "username".

"username"@mydefaultdomain.com

```
@observer
class Register extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      verifyPassword: "",
      isEmailInvalid: true
    };
  }
```

Comment: Adding a fake domain at the end of a username is not a good way to achieve username authentication. It is recommended to ask the user for both their username and email address and use the email to sign in. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467492/how-to-provide-user-login-with-a-username-and-not-an-email).

Answer (score 1):

Ok so basically you want to join two string in which first part is variable.
That can be done by using javascript predefined function "concat()".

```
 var str1 = "Hello";
 var str2 = str1.concat("@gmail.com");
```

Comment: Why not use `str1 + '@gmail.com'`? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) actually recommends using the `+` operator instead.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help.
So @KeroppiMomo , where should I add that line of code?

Comment: @fn2505 wherever you are calling that state variable implement it there.

Comment: @SIDDHARTH VARSHNEY 
forgive me I'm still learning.
Should I implement it in register.js near    
 this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",?
sorry for bad english

Comment: https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/how-to-work-with-forms-inputs-and-events-in-react-c337171b923b Check out this link to lean how onChange events are used to set states